# Why is HttpContext.Current set to null?

Tags: httpcontext

we are trying to access the user profile properties via SOM. Code is taken from reference as mentioned below.

My question is: **Why is HttpContext.Current set to null?. Code works even if we comment out this line. What is the purpose?**

[There is an article about why it is set to null here.](http://blogs.technet.com/b/sharepointdevelopersupport/archive/2012/11/02/runwithelevatedprivileges-does-not-work-with-userprofile-api.aspx)

Code:

```
string accountName = SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.LoginName;
Logger.info("ProfileUserControl:btnSave_Click() Saving user profile properties.");
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
{
    SPSite sc = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.ID);
    SPServiceContext context = SPServiceContext.GetContext(sc);
    //ServerContext context = ServerContext.GetContext(sc);
    HttpContext currentContext = HttpContext.Current;
    HttpContext.Current = null;
    UserProfileManager profileManager = new UserProfileManager(context);
    UserProfile userProfile = profileManager.GetUserProfile(accountName);    
    userProfile[PropertyConstants.WorkPhone].Value = txtWorkPhone.Text.Trim();
    userProfile[PropertyConstants.CellPhone].Value = txtMobilePhone.Text.Trim();
    userProfile[PropertyConstants.HomePhone].Value = txtHomePhone.Text.Trim();
    userProfile[PropertyConstants.School].Value = txtSchool.Text.Trim();
    userProfile[PropertyConstants.Skills].Value = txtSkills.Text.Trim();
    userProfile.Commit();
    HttpContext.Current = currentContext;
    //UserProfile userProfile = SPSparshService.GetUserProfile("");
});
```

Reference:
http://www.fewlines4biju.com/2011/01/how-to-save-user-profile-properties.html

Comment: Ideally when is this done?

Comment: Do you feel there is any drawback of using this on  production server?

Comment: Please post your added link as an answer (with an abstract), that i really good information! Questionable if this is still valid for 2013, but I would expect it to bee

Comment: I am unable to understand the exact concept. Can you post the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[From the link you supplied](http://blogs.technet.com/b/sharepointdevelopersupport/archive/2012/11/02/runwithelevatedprivileges-does-not-work-with-userprofile-api.aspx):

> In case your business needs require users apart from Administrators
>   for User Profile Service Application to be able to create organization
>   profiles (not sure why you’d want that though), the workaround is to
>   set HttpContext.Current to null like code below.
>
> ```
> SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate() {
>     HttpContext httpCtx = HttpContext.Current;
>     HttpContext.Current = null;
>
>     using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://yourserver/"))
>     {
>         // code omitted here
>     } // end of using
>     HttpContext.Current = httpCtx; });
> ```
>
> The workaround makes the service account of User Profile Service Application to execute the
>   code. The service account should be in Administrators for User Profile
>   Service Application with Full Control permission.

So, setting the HttpContext to null should only be done when you have to let users not having "Manage Profiles" permissions on the UPS to do changes to UPS.

The fact that `RunWithElevatedPrivileges` does not work is probably due to the `UserProfileManager` not being part on the `Microsoft.SharePoint API`, but rather the `Microsoft.Office.Server` API.